# Auto Digit grouping with two decimal places in JavaFx

Tags: javafx, digit, formatted-text

How to Automatically Format User Input on a text field that will do grouping digit with two decimal place automated when user type on that text field.

what is the best way to do this.

Example like you type in Windows Calculator When Digit Groping activated.

Like in this picture

[Digit Groping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uExFj.jpg)

in the picture shows automatic digit groping when user type number.

Thank's

Comment: Can you provide an example, how you want to look like?

Comment: http://fxexperience.com/2012/02/moneyfield/

Comment: @Sunflame I've added an example

Comment: use a TextFormatter

Comment: @Sedrick I have tried and have not succeeded

Comment: @user7182326 have you tried using a `TextFormatter` as @kleopatra suggested?

Comment: @Sunflame I have tried suggest. TextFormatter only show what I want after TextField Lost focus